# using a UILocalNotification to play a sound that's not in the app bundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

Is it possible to use a UILocalNotification (or any outside notification/long-term multitasking) to play a sound outside an app that's NOT in the main application bundle? [Documentation for UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says the soundName attribute must be the name of a file in the main bundle. I threw together a quick app that confirms this.

Is there a way to get around this restriction? I was thinking something with aliases, where the alias is in the app bundle and points to a known path in the Documents folder... but I guess the Documents folder isn't exactly known.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Kevboh, Were you able to use sounds from document directory in UILocalnotification sound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in a sandboxed environment, its not possible.