# In UILocalNotification sound set recorded audio

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification, audio

I need your help. Actually the problem is that i want to set the recorded audio file (which is saved in application document directory) to be used as sound for local notification. I searched a lot and concluded that sound file that we have to use in local notification must be in Application Bundle. So if any idea about saving recorded audio file in Application bundle at run time will also do my task

Answer (score 6):

No you can not play an audio file that is not in the bundle and you can not modify the application bundle at runtime. One reason why Apple requires all sounds for local notifications to be bundled with the application may be for security reasons, that would make it possible for all bundled files to be checked for security risks during the review process.

Comment: so you are saying that i cant use recorded audio file in local Notification?

Comment: No you can not, I had a project where I needed to do the same thing and just ended up having to bundle about 8-10 sounds the user could choose from. Now if your local notification fires while your app is open you can obviously play the recorded file (but that is not ideal)

Comment: Any reason for the -1? Playing audio files is simply not permitted and neither is modifying the application bundle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611417/using-a-uilocalnotification-to-play-a-sound-thats-not-in-the-app-bundle

Comment: This app seems to be able to do it. http://itunes.apple.com/sg/app/aida-reminder-lite-voice-reminders/id469454389?mt=8&ls=1

Comment: @honcheng No, it doesn't. I tried it, but it plays the voice reminder when you open the app, not when the notification fires.