# Play recorded audio in UILocalNotification

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, audio, uilocalnotification

I am working on AlarmClock application.In this user records his/her sound and set the alarms.For this I am using UILocalNotification and in this I want to set recorded sound when alert comes.
The issue is in set sound to UILocalNotification.I surf for that and found you have to save recorded file in application's main bundle not in document directory.So I surf for write file in application's main bundle and I found that you can not write file in main bundle.

So please give me suggestion for how to play recorded audio when notification comes.

http://itunes.apple.com/sg/app/aida-reminder-lite-voice-reminders/id469454389?mt=8&ls=1

this application works fine with same functionality that I want.

Comment: where does it say you can only play a sound saved within the application's main bundle?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann The below link.So i am confused http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040551/in-uilocalnotification-sound-set-recorded-audio

Answer (score 3):

I think this is not possible. UINotification can only search the main bundle for custom sound resource and you can not write to the main bundle at runtime.

Comment: Yes i also think so but in iTunes "aida reminder" application i think it will work in paid version.So i am not sure about whether its possible or not..Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

As of **iOS 10** you may use sound files for notification located in `Library/Sounds` directory.

Look inside the `UNNotificationSound.h` header file, the description comment of method:

```
public convenience init(named name: String)
```

says:

> The name of a sound file to be played for the notification. The sound
>   file must be contained in the app’s bundle or in the Library/Sounds
>   folder of the app's data container. If files exist in both locations
>   then the file in the app's data container will be preferred.

So, if you have any change to put external sound files into the `Library/Sounds` folder, you can just:

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Title"
content.subtitle = ""
content.body = "Message"
content.userInfo = nil
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.init(named: "sound-from-server.m4a")
// ...
```